# GWT how to change the css at run time

Tags: gwt

We have a requirement of accessibility in our next application and we will need customized themes for this.
The first goal to achieve is to be able to increase and decrease the font size in the application. For this we will have two buttons, one to increase, the other to decrease the size of text in all components. You can use Enterprise Blue as a reference theme. You can see an example of this at the URL: http://emag.governoeletronico.gov.br/emag/#. You can click on "Aumentar Fonte " and "Diminuir Fonte".

Any idea how can i acheive this in GWT/SmartGWT

thanks

Comment: ,Change the title if possible to how to change the "css" at run time,So it wont restrict to font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is [RootPanel.getBodyElement()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#getBodyElement%28%29).

The most Convenient way is to apply classes on `body element`.

There are multiple ways to do it.

```
RootPanel.get("body").setStyleName("newbodyclass"); //Not recommended.
```

**Efficient way**

```
RootPanel.getBodyElement().setClassName("newbodyclass"); //Recommended
```

**Few new ways**:

```
Document.get().getBody().setClassName("newbodyclass");
```

Finally best for you problem:

```
Document.get().getBody().getStyle().setFontSize(value, unit);
```

Comment: Thanks it works in GWT , but in smartGWT it works for the background color for example , But not for the Font size .                          .newbodyclass{
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: yellow;                             
} :::RootPanel.getBodyElement().setClassName("newbodyclass");      ::: here i am calling this css, which works in GWT but font size   not changing in smartGWT ,                                               Any advice

Comment: color changed to yellow ??

Comment: Junai ,can you please check with by putting !important beside the font size ??

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but it didnt work.. any idea what could be the reason

Answer (score 1):

```
static Label lblNewLabel = new Label("New label");
Button btnNewButton = new Button("New button");
private int fontSize=10;

btnNewButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    fontSize += 5;
    lblNewLabel.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(fontSize  , Unit.PX);
  }
});
```